# asynchronous loading html String in UIwebview iOS

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiwebview

I've a webview in which htmlString to be load which contains text and images. As, it loaded successfully by using

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Now, during loading web view engage the main thread and did not let scroll until it gets loaded. So, I tried to do async loading in web view but failed as Xcode not allowed me to load web view in background thread. Can anyone please help in this matter

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal I found an alternative solution by adding a shimmer effect as subview during loading but couldn't able to achieve async loading.

Comment: Ok! Actually I am having webviews in table view cells and thats why it's a problem.